# QGIS not importing correct IPython version for IPython QGIS console plugin

Tags: qgis, error, qgis-python-console, ipython

I am trying to run the Ipython console plugin in QGIS 2.18

After installing the plugin, I tried running it, and got the following
error:

```
You need to install IPython 3.1.0 (and then restart QGIS) before running
this IPyConsole plugin.
IPython can be installed with pip install "ipython[all]==3.1.0". More
informations about IPython installation on
https://ipython.org/install.html [1]
```

So I followed the instructions, and ran `sudo pip install ipython[all]==3.1.0` ... the installation was successful, but then when
I restarted QGIS and tried to open the Ipython console, I got exactly
the same error message. I double-checked and when I run ipython from the terminal it is indeed running 3.1.0 now:

```
Python 3.5.0+ (default, Oct 11 2015, 09:05:38) 

IPython 3.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
```

But if I go into the QGIS default console, and type in:

```
import IPython; 
IPython.__version__
```

it returns: `'2.4.1'` ... so for some reason, QGIS isn't using the same version that runs when typing ipython in the shell.

What else do I need to do? Why would QGIS not be able to recognize that
I have the correct version of ipython installed? (I am running Linux Mint 18 btw)

Comment: You install Ipython 3.1.0 for Python 3.5 but QGIS 2.18 uses Python 2.7.x, with a 2.4.1 version installed

Comment: Thanks gene. How would I install the correct version for Python 2.7.x so that QGIS could use it instead of the system version?

Comment: Using the Python console of QGIS, you can know the Python path of the version used by the application and use the suitable pip

Comment: gene - Sorry, I'm not very experienced with Python, and I'm not quite sure what you mean by "the suitable pip". When I do `sys.version` from the QGIS console, it returns `2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) \n[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]'` ... so how do I know what pip version to use, and how do I use it instead of the system-wide version (when I run "pip" in terminal)? Originally I tried installing ipython using `sudo pip install ipython[all]==3.1.0` -- what should I have done differently?